# Open file from Batch location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch program (let's say batch1) that has to open another batch file(batch2) from the location of batch1. if you don't know what I mean, I want batch1 to act as an .html file. by that I mean, and file reference would be from the location of the batch1 file.

So think of this:

A Folder named "BatchFolder" has 2 files in it. 1 Folder named "Data", and another named batch1.bat

In the folder "Data", there is a batch file batch2.bat

I want to be able to say `"Start "Data\batch2.bat"` in batch1.bat to Open the batch2.bat file.

I want to do this so you can move BatchFolder anywhere, and the batch1.bat will still work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lose the start command. It is NOT the normal way to start programs. ` "Data\batch2.bat"` is sufficient. Although batch files don't return as standard. You may want to do `call  "Data\batch2.bat"`. See `Start /?` and `Call /?` for a discussion on how to start programs. See the end of my answer here for a brief summary - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371443/what-do-all-commands-in-batch-mean-and-do.

Comment: Use the /D switch with the `START` command so that it sets the working directory to the location of the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The `%0` script argument is a script name. You can extract a script drive, path, file name, extension parts of your script.

```
rem  Get script dir, with '\' on the end
rem  Example: c:\folder\
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0

rem  Trim the last '\'
rem  Example: c:\folder
set SCRIPT_DIR=%SCRIPT_DIR:~0,-1%
```

So you can use `"%SCRIPT_DIR%\Data\batch2.bat"` path to reference your second batch file.